# How do you use the command 'watch'?

Tags: command-line

I want to know exactly what the command `watch` is and how it is used to watch files and folders. How do you operate it from a command-line terminal?

Comment: welcome to AU! [..:: AskUbuntu Tour ::..](http://askubuntu.com/about)

Answer (score 13):

From `man watch`

> watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

Say you want to monitor your network device status, you can use in terminal,

```
watch -n 2 nmcli dev
```

It will give you output as below which will be updated in every 2 seconds (as I used `-n 2`)

```
Every 2.0s: nmcli dev                                       Sat Jan 18 23:09:35 2014

DEVICE     TYPE              STATE
eth0       802-3-ethernet    connected
eth1       802-11-wireless   unavailable
```

If you want to keep watch on the changes of your files folders in a directory, use

```
watch -n 5 ls /path/to/directory
```

It will show you the list of files and folders in that directory which will be updated in every 5 seconds.

Comment: Even you can use `watch -d ls /path/to/directory`. It will update the list in every 2 seconds by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the command `watch`, it basically run a command every so often, by default every 2 seconds, and shows the output fullscreen.

For a fairly lengthy example, open terminal, and enter:

```
sleep 5; echo "hello world" >> ~/newfile.txt
```

This will wait 5 seconds, and then output "hello world" to the text file ~/newfile.txt

Don't execute it, but open a new - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Enter this, and run it:

```
watch -n 2.5 ls ~
```

This will tell `watch` to run the command `ls ~` *(which lists the contents of the home directory `~`)*, every 2.5 seconds *`-n 2.5`*.

Go back to the tab with the `sleep..`, and run that command, then switch back to the tab with the `watch` command in. You should see the `newfile.txt` ventually appear in the output.

For more info, view the [manual page for `watch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/watch.1) with:

```
man watch
```