# watch with arp produce no output

Tags: command-line, networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

I would like to display the output table of the [`arp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/arp.8.html) command *every 30 seconds*, so that I can monitor [Address Resolution Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) traffic on my network.

Unfortunately `arp` doesn't have such option. It only prints the current content of the table once, like this:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.103            ether   48:e2:44:d5:7a:97   C                     eth0
192.168.0.1              ether   c8:3a:35:49:77:48   C                     eth0
```

So I usually end up running `arp` several times manually to detect any changes in the table entries, which is not very sophisticated.

In order to automate this task, I read that the [`watch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/watch.1.html) command allows to repeat commands automatically ([1](https://askubuntu.com/q/430382/643185), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10646/211318), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13593771/3599179)). Therefore I prepended `watch -n 30` to `arp` like this:

```
watch -n 30 arp
```

However, when I run it I don't get any kind of output. The table is not even printed once.

Why is that? How can I solve this?

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/407413/643185) shows a working example with `nmcli dev`, so I see no reason why this should not be possible to do with `arp`.

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work and it indeed works here exactly as you entered it:

watch -n 30 arp

The only thing I can think of would be to look at the results of the command "export" and make sure your display isn't set to something funky.

I ran the watch command from a standard terminal shell that comes with the standard Ubuntu distribution.  Nothing special here...

As a test you could try forcing an output redirect:

watch -n 5 arp >> test_file

Comment: After restarting my machine it works fine now. I am using Xubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus. Thank you.